# Benefits and limitations of different implementation approaches

Tags: android

I just started learning Android development and I read there was basically 3 main approaches to 'build a view' which are :

> - Java-based: Use Java to define Strings, lay out window, create GUI controls, and assign event handlers. Like Swing programming.
> - XML-based: Use XML files to define Strings, lay out window, create GUI controls, and assign event handlers. The Java method will read the
>     layout from XML file and pass it to setContentView
> - Hybrid: Use an XML file to define Strings, lay out window and create GUI controls. Use Java to assign event handlers

**What are the benefits and limitations of these 3 different approaches ?**

**Which one should be rather used by a beginner or a confirmed programmer ?**

I'm not asking for subjective answer here ( before being flagged :) ). 
There must be some **facts** that make these approaches different from one another (speed, maintainability, readability...)

Comment: (I still think this question is open-ended. However) **XML** design is fast and visual, but it is static. I use it to create the building blocks. Designing with **Java** dynamic and has more features, but it can be long-winded (especially the LayoutParams classes!). I use this for dynamic data and putting decoration on my XML foundation.

Comment: It's like HTML vs HTML + PHP. One is static and visually easier, the other one gives you more possibilities but you might not need so much complexity (like almost everybody on Android). Unless you have specific restrictions, I advice to use XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XML-based is like using CSS for a webpage.** Using XML separates concerns neatly into the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern. If everything is specified in XML, then your activity can utilize different layout files for different screens, and the presentation of these elements can easily be updated by just changing to new XML files. This is good software development practice and greatly helps when it comes time to redesign or reuse components. In some cases you may still need to dynamically set some things in Java, but you should try to put all presentation-related stuff in the XML files.

The event handlers should still be set and defined in Java, in my opinion. That is not related to presentation and thus does not belong in the XML files. I do not use the onclick XML attributes. Also, if you set it in the onclick attribute, you can break the connection if you refactor the method name in Java but forget to update the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using XML as much as possible is that all the Android tools provide support for this style of programming (UI editors, etc.). If you do everything in code, you're on your own. (Want to see the effect of a change to your code-based layout? Build your app and run it in the emulator. With an XML-based layout, you can preview it right in the XML editor where you are making the changes.)

Regarding event handlers, the main advantage of declaring them in XML (e.g., with an `android:onClick` property) is that you don't have to declare the event handler classes. The advantage here, though is not particularly strong, and I often use what you describe as a hybrid approach.

I'd advise beginning Android programmers (whether experienced with other programming or not) to gain a strong foundation in the XML style that Android pushes.